# How to know if a card game deck has improved?

Tags: statistics

I'm a casual player of a 2-player collectible card game (Magic The Gathering to name it) where your craft your own decks using the cards you gather.

Each deck, played a huge number of times against various other decks will converge to a certain win rate.

Now, the complexity is that each game is different because of the cards you draw and the power of the deck can change a lot.

Is there a mathematical way to determine if, by changing a few cards, my deck gets statistically better? If so, how many games do I have to play to know for sure?

Comment: Does the win rate depend only on the deck? Or also the skills of the player? The first question to ask is: how do you measure the quality of a deck? Can you assign a unique numerical value to a deck?

Comment: It depends on the skills of the player though they don't vary over time. One can assume the player will play its deck the same way every time. The quality of the deck is related to its win rate but the complexity of the game makes it really hard to give an objective score to a deck without actually playing it.